# Por que não temos o "teste" (pegadinha) na fila de análise?

Tags: novo-recurso, status-pronto, filas-de-análise

No StackOverflow.com na fila de análise, principalmente nas edições, tem uma espécie de teste (pegadinha pra testar a atenção do usuário) que é o **Review audit**:

[image: Review audit]

Eu percebi 2 ou 3 usuários no SOpt que fazem edições ou fecham (abrem) postagens erroneamente, algumas coisas sem sentido até.

São poucos e geralmente eles não fazem por mal, é por não entender direito o que está acontecendo.

Claro que poderíamos ver caso a caso, mas esta questão não é sobre isto. Quero propor que o SOpt também tenha o **Review audit**, isto ajuda a treinar os colaboradores e ao meu ver ajuda com estes tipos de problemas.

Comment: Eu *acho* que o Gabe tem autonomia para ligar e desligar isso. Concordo com você que está na hora de termos os *audits*.

Comment: @bfavaretto Se é tão fácil como ligar/desligar por que não ligar e ver o que acontece?

Comment: @ramaral Porque não é tão fácil, e não sou eu quem faz. Mas certamente chegou a hora de termos as auditorias. Vou ver como habilitar aqui

Comment: @Gabe Julgo que será útil para obrigar a que sejamos mais cuidadosos na analisa.

Comment: Acho que o problema original, quando isto foi discutido a primeira vez, era ter conteúdo/amostragem suficiente para gerar os audits. Agora acredito que já tem material.

Comment: @Gabe Existe algum critério na escolha das perguntas/respostas que me são dadas a analisar na fila? Ou em cada momento todos vemos a mesma fila de análise?

Comment: Por favor, veja a [minha resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4839/6), @ramaral - que depende da fila.

Comment: @Gabe é suposto a review audit ser constante? Tipo a cada 2 ou 3 revisões?

Comment: @JorgeB. Você tem uma chance de 1 em 20 de receber "ser auditado", pra cada fila. É só a probabilidade, então podem ocorrer mais vezes ou menos vezes. No seu caso, suas auditorias foram quase sempre em filas diferentes (só ocorreu 2 vezes na de baixa qualidade)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Esta é uma boa ideia. **Feito!**

Note-se que como não testamos auditorias aqui ainda, podem haver algumas esquisitices. Se algo aparentar não estar funcionando corretamente (ou não ter sido traduzido corretamente), é o caso de [postar um relato de bug aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=an%C3%A1lise%20bug).

Os critérios pelos quais perguntas ou respostas são escolhidos para uso como auditorias dependem da fila, mas em geral:

- **Boas auditorias** são perguntas ou respostas que têm atraído muitos votos positivos e nenhuma sinalização importante nem votos para fechar.
- **Más auditorias** são perguntas ou respostas que têm atraído uma quantidade significativa de ações negativas (votos ou sinalizações).

Até termos certeza de que as auditorias estão funcionando corretamente aqui, eu deixei os *review-bans* automáticos (baseados no histórico de falhas nas auditorias) desligados. Digam-me em uma semana, ou assim que for o caso, se vocês gostariam que os habilitem também.

Da mesma forma, me digam se esta tradução automática é ofensiva ou ilegível. Na verdade, falem para o Gabe, assim ele pode me dizer em inglês. (nota do editor: isto também vale para a [atual edição da resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/4839/revisions).

Exemplo:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Muito obrigado! Acredito que isto será de grande ajuda.