# Auditoria na fila de análise

Tags: debate, filas-de-análise, auditoria

Referente:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/56361
- [Quais são e como se relacionam as tecnologias .NET para se desenvolver sistemas web?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111209/quais-s%C3%A3o-e-como-se-relacionam-as-tecnologias-net-para-se-desenvolver-sistemas)

Essa pergunta está no SOPT, aqui no meta creio que ela pode se enquadrar, mas votei para fechá-la como pergunta lá no SOPT porque usei de base as definições do escopo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

pergunta **não tem à ver** com...

- um problema específico de programação
- um algoritmo de software
- ferramentas comuns entre programadores
- problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software
- dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicados ao desenvolvimento de software

Visto que não se enquadra em nenhum ponto da **central de ajuda** eu votei para fechar e coloquei nas observações o porquê da decisão.

Quando cliquei recebi a mensagem **Você não foi aprovado**.

> (Isso era uma auditoria com o objetivo de verificar se você estava
>   prestando atenção)

Como o sistema julga a minha **falta de atenção?** Estou observando de forma sistemática o sistema deveria no mínimo "errar junto" pois ele deveria pegar uma base de conhecimento diga-se de passagem o escopo da central de ajuda e verificar se a pergunta se enquadra, e foi exatamente isso que fiz, e **depois se** a comunidade analisar de forma abstrata e julgá-la válida votarem para aceitá-la, estamos no caminho errado em aceitar primeiro perguntas fora do escopo e depois ter quer debater para retirá-las, isso vai dar muito mais trabalho, e ao meu ver é irracional seria o mesmo que aceitar tudo o que não esta no escopo e filtrar depois com base no escopo e debates.

Bom, se a pergunta se enquadra lá nas perguntas então **é preciso ao menos fazer uma atualização na [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para deixar isso mais claro**, acabei de voltar de uma penalidade por votar rápido demais e já vou voltar p/ geladeira? Se for o caso amigos foi bom ter feito parte do SOPT achei muito proveitoso fazer parte enquanto era uma democracia onde o meu voto falava por mim, não quero participar de uma votação onde tenho uma auditoria me informando que a minha opinião esta errada, uma vez que a **opinião é minha** eu deveria ter o direito de livre manifestação e direito ao voto para fechar, por mais imbecil que fosse o meu motivo.

Os demais votantes com motivos mais **justos** e de **maioria aceita** no caso apenas 5 pensadores de iguais opiniões bastaria para prevalecer sobre a minoria que joga fora o próprio voto, é assim que funciona por exemplo o wikipédia, você vai e edita um artigo por "achar" que esta mais certo e logo depois sua edição é desfeita, sem ressentimentos apenas com um comentário simples de bom embasamento e maioria concordante sobrevalerá sobre os demais, o voto aqui também deveria seguir este caminho e acho que no começo era assim por isso a pergunta só muda de status com 5 votos de iguais concordância.

Outro ponto a se pensar é o que te importa se uma pessoa vota "errado"(contraria a sua opinião)?

A pergunta se torna legitimada pela maioria dos votos, logo como acredito que a maioria queira fazer o bem então será consequência natural a pergunta ser votada de forma correta pois sempre teremos mais gente tentando ajudar do que bagunçar, se isso não fosse uma verdade o SOPT nem existiria.

Mesmo assim sabendo que os votos mais **certos** irão prevalecer sobre os votos **errados** ainda assim devemos deixar o voto livre para alguém mesmo que por  ignorância vote errado, deve ser aceito esse voto para se valer a democracia, é assim que democracia funciona, se você sabia onde o Brasil iria parar com o atual governo, você com sabedoria deveria ter influenciados as outras pessoas a votarem em outro partido, mas você não tem o direito de votar pelos outros.

Não digo aqui que a ferramenta de auditoria seja uma má ideia, mas do jeito que está não está bom, está ferindo o direito da subjetividade, acho que a auditoria poderia somente informar que a maioria de N pessoas aceitam a pergunta e só você que não, ai eu poderia entrar num debate e procurar me informar e me adequar com os demais, do jeito que está a auditoria não me ensinou nada, talvez quem sabe nesses casos já deixar um link para uma room no chat para debater, ou deixar uma mensagem com base em que ela foi aprovada ou rejeitada, precisa ser feito um algo a mais se realmente a intenção é fazer com que os votantes reflitam do que simplesmente colocar uma mensagem dizendo **errou** sem explicar o motivo.

Answer (score 9):

> não quero participar de uma votação onde tenho uma auditoria me informando que a minha opnião esta errada, uma vez que a opnião é minha eu deveria ter o direito de livre manifestação e direito ao voto para fechar, por mais imbecil que fosse o meu motivo.

O sistema não tem como saber a sua opinião, ele não é humano. As auditorias foram implementadas para evitar que as pessoas analisem mecanicamente as publicações, e não para julgar se determinada opinião é "certa" ou "errada" – até porque esses conceitos são relativos.

O algoritmo das auditorias funciona com base na (suposta) opinião "da comunidade", representada pelas características do post (comprimento, respostas, votos, sinalizações etc.). A pergunta não está "de verdade" na fila de análise, ela foi enxertada lá pelo algoritmo
. 
Além disso, esse sistema [acabou de ser implementado aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4839) – aliás, [a pedido da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4238)  e sem nenhuma oposição no meta – e ainda está sendo treinado/calibrado.

Se você acha que a pergunta não é exemplar do que deve permanecer aberto, argumente a favor disso. Se você tiver apoio suficiente, talvez a pergunta possa ser colocada em algum tipo de lista de exceções. Ou vote pra fechar, e dê elementos para o sistema desconfiar dessa pergunta. Já adianto que para mim é uma pergunta totalmente válida.

Comment: +1 cada um tem sua opinão e esta deve ser respeitada, mas eu acho essa auditoria excelente, pois ela as vezes faz a gente parar pra pensar sobre a analise, eu já recebi 2 como falha, e discordei, mas o aviso me serviu de alerta pra ficar mais atento aos itens da fila em geral.

Comment: @bfavaretto o sistema de auditoria já definiu como certa, já desconsiderou meu voto, ou seja quem votar junto comigo irá receber a mesma mensagem, "você votou errado", e isso é o mesmo que me dar uma ficha para votar onde o X já esta marcado, se você marcar o X em outro lugar seu voto é anulado tendo por obrigação deixar o X já marcado prevalecer

Answer (score 6):

## Sobre a pergunta

Eu respeito completamente sua opinião em achar a pergunta *off-topic*.

Aliás, tenho que confessar que criei essa pergunta propositalmente para ficar um pouco "em cima do muro".

Fique à vontade para votar pelo fechamento dela se achar adequado.

## Sobre o que é *on-topic*

Entretanto, algo que eu queria que todos aqui no site refletissem é sobre as restrições de tópicos.

Isso já foi discutido bastante, inclusive com algumas pessoas sugerindo que algumas perguntas que seriam do escopo do SUpt. Claro que é um assunto polêmico e vários usuários tem opinião contrária.

Porém, o Gabe já deixou claro em várias ocasiões que os itens da lista de *on-topic* são poucos e genéricos de propósito, com o objetivo de deixar a comunidade definir os limites.

**Meu** entendimento sobre a pergunta é que ela se enquadra mais ou menos nas seguintes categorias:

> problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software
>   dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicados ao desenvolvimento de software

Determinar o papel de um uma ou mais tecnologias dentro de uma plataforma para resolver problemas específicos de programação parece bem dentro do contexto para mim.

Pode não envolver codificação direta, mas certamente definição de arquitetura é um problema do desenvolvimento de software.

Em Arquitetura de Software, quase todas as perguntas desse tipo vão apresentar os mesmos "problemas".

A diferença entre perguntas que deveriam ser aceitas ou não, **na minha opinião**, dependem do quanto elas estão **bem definida**.

Perguntas de arquitetura precisam ser bem feitas para ter o contexto correto, o que nem sempre é fácil.

Enfim, minha opinião é que não podemos jogar fora toda pergunta que seja conceitual sobre tecnologia apenas porque de vez em quando alguém faz perguntas ruins do tipo "como eu faço um sistema na linguagem X".

## Sobre votos

Quanto à questão de serem 5 votos para fechar ou reabrir uma questão, eu também acho que isso nem sempre é justo. Uma minoria pode causar e às vezes efetivamente causa danos.

Entretanto, não vejo muitos alternativas a esse sistema. Por exemplo, se fosse por maioria, teria que ter uma data de corte ou uma quantidade mínima, caso contrário um voto para fechar iria suspender a questão. E os usuários que não retiram o voto mesmo depois da edição também causariam certa injustiça.

Enfim, pode ser que existe algum modelo melhor, mas seria o caso de pensarmos em como melhorar, pois não é algo simples.

## Sobre democracia e votos

Só porque falamos em democracia não significa que todo mundo tem o direito de votar como quiser e quando quiser.

Mesmo no mundo real, votar **não** é um direito absoluto e [existem vários motivos pelos quais você pode perder o seu](http://www.tse.jus.br/imprensa/noticias-tse/boletim/mais-de-800-mil-brasileiros-estao-com-os-direitos-politicos-suspensos).

Não estou dizendo que todos os casos são justos, mas que o método de detecção automático é como um policial que tenta pregar possíveis usuários depredando o site.

Comment: utluiz, há contradição no sistema de auditoria nesse caso, pois você me diz para ficar a vontade para votar em fecha-la, mas a auditoria me diz que estou errado em votar dessa maneira e simplesmente anula meu voto e minha opnião, é muito mais que tendencioso em dizer que é uma pergunta válida é literalmente imposta com um pseudo mecanismo de opnião,

Comment: @SneepSNinjA ele quis dizer que você pode votar para fechá-la se desejar, indo direto na pergunta e deixando seu voto por lá.

Comment: @Math, não podemos usar auditoria autoritaria flagando e tendencionando uma pergunta como válida ou inválida, via sistema é possível descartar o que esta fora do escopo, mas as perguntas mais subjetivas nesse caso é importante abrir para uma votação democrática, você pode achar que essa pergunta é válida eu continuo me valendo que não e assim meu voto deve ser registrado para que demais possam refletir nessa direção também, do jeito que esta é influenciar na decisão puxando votos em uma direção, vocês estão querendo decidir por todos fazendo isso, estão praticando **boca de urna**

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Ninguém está querendo decidir por ninguém, a pergunta foi escolhida pelo algoritmo da auditoria. Se você for lá na pergunta e votar pra fechar ou sinalizar, provavelmente ela deixa de ser usada em auditorias – além de ir "de verdade" pra fila de análise e permitir que outros validem ou não a sua opinião.

Comment: Eu imaginei que os ADM selecionava perguntas para a auditoria, bom talvez eu esteja relutante por ser uma adaptação da qual com certeza ainda desconheço algumas coisas, estou tentando ver a vantagem nisso tudo, vou tentar continuar com a fila de análise mais um pouco e ver se ainda vou ter interesse em continuar, só vi até agora que em vez de agilizar processos estão criando gargalos essa é a minha primeira impressão disso tudo.

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Infelizmente, quando há aumento de volume ou se deseja aumentar a qualidade, inevitavelmente um pouco de burocracia tem que ser adicionada para evitar o caos. Como você já entendeu, o novo mecanismo de auditoria da fila de análise seleciona automaticamente questões para verificar se os usuários estão prestando atenção. Nesse caso, o algoritmo parece selecionar perguntas de boa reputação. Não tenho certeza, mas parece que pega o que não tem nenhum negativo. Você caiu num "corner case", isto é, justamente uma questão que alguns usuários poderiam contestar de forma legítima.

Comment: Nesse caso, me parece realmente um pouco injusto. Além disso, como quase todo tipo de auditoria que já vi na vida, o algoritmo é um pouco "burro" no sentido de que ele não tem como analisar a intenção do que está ali, apenas números. Portanto, obviamente o sistema não é perfeito e eu vou mais longe: ele está reforçando um "comportamento de bando", afinal se "x usuários votaram a fator então ele está supondo que você também deveria fazer o mesmo.

Comment: Por outro lado, pode ser bom para quem começa a usar o site e não sabe votar. Quem já tem o seu jeito próprio, o seu caso, uma vez que já conhece o mecanismo, basta tomar um pouco pouco mais de cuidado. Por exemplo, quando você ver uma flag estranha numa pergunta com votos positivos, abra ela numa outra aba e veja se existe algo que confirme a flag. Enfim, não vou dizer que novas situações estranhas não possam surgir, até porque o Gabe já falou que o algoritmo precisa ser treinado, mas acredito que com o tempo todos vão pegar o jeito e isso é bom, porque significa que estão prestando atenção.