# Fila de análise: Primeiras publicações

Tags: debate, suporte

Notei que a seguinte resposta estava na fila de análise para primeiras publicações: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/138522

Classificada como:

> Esta é a primeira resposta publicada por um usuário novo. Ajude-os a
>   aprender a usar o site analisando sua publicação.

O AR não estava aparecendo no momento da análise:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O curioso é que o AR não é um usuário novo, acredito que a resposta não deveria ter entrado para a fila de análise, esse comportamento é normal?

Comment: Isso é normal, oculta o AR para evitar algum tipo de analise parcial

Comment: @rray o que me chamou a atenção na verdade, foi o fato do AR não ser um usuário novo (havia esquecido de mencionar esse fato na pergunta).

Comment: pegadinha do malandro pra confundir glu glu ie ie;)

Comment: Isso são os testes feitos nas filas. Se mostrar um usuário com muita reputação a pessoa que analisa sabe rapidamente que é um teste e vota apropriadamente. Se mostrar como usuário novo obriga a pessoa a ter atenção e analisar a serio.

Comment: Entendi, interessante.

Comment: @Henrique assim que você termina sua ação, é mostrado se você foi *Aprovado* ou *Reprovado* no teste.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assim como o **[Review Audits](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4238/66203)** acontece em todas, nessa fila de análise, o mesmo acontece.

O princípio do teste é observar a atenção do usuário, para ver qual a ação que ele está realizando nas filas, se estão sendo corretas ou erradas. Entenda também que o critério usado pelo sistema, para definir a ação correta (na maioria das vezes, a não ser quando o teste está errado) é ser baseado na qualidade da pergunta e [não pelo AP](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6021/66203). E afinal de contas, é uma **[pegadinha](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6504/fila-de-an%C3%A1lise-primeiras-publica%C3%A7%C3%B5es#comment25201_6504)**. Se estivesse certo não teria graça ;).