# Como funciona a auditoria de avaliação de análises?

Tags: debate

Recebi a seguinte mensagem ao analisar uma resposta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso aconteceu porque eu dei -1 para a resposta. Ao meu ver a resposta está incorreta. Como proceder nesse caso?

Eis o link da pergunta:
[Qual é a diferença entre i++ e ++i?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243108/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-i-e-i)

> Há uma diferença ligeira entre os dois. O i++ ("pós incremento")
>   retorna o valor inicial de i e o ++i ("pré incremento") retorna o
>   valor incrementado de i.

Ambos i++ e ++i incrementam o valor. A diferença é que o i++ primeiro atribui e depois incrementa e o ++i primeiro incrementa e depois atribui. O i++ não retorna o valor inicial de i. A intenção de quem respondeu foi provavelmente dizer a mesma coisa, mas ao meu ver não ficou claro o suficiente. Acho que cabe a quem avalia decidir se a resposta ou pergunta é boa ou ruim. Avaliação é algo subjetivo. Essa auditoria do StackOverflow é realizada baseada em que?

Comment: Foi esta que você avaliou e que discorda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/142676 ?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim.

Comment: Poderia explicar aonde exatamente esta o erro, quero dizer ao menos a minha interpretação foi diferente da sua, a não ser que eu não tenha entendido o problema.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Fila de análise: Primeiras publicações](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6504/fila-de-an%c3%a1lise-primeiras-publica%c3%a7%c3%b5es)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Por isso que falei que a análise é subjetiva. Para mim a resposta não está clara o suficiente. Embora eu concorde que várias pessoas podem achar que a resposta é suficiente. A pergunta aqui no meta foi mais para entender como a auditoria era feita. A resposta do Maniero esclarece bem a minha dúvida. Aproveito para questionar pq a minha pergunta foi marcada como duplicada. Essa pergunta não tem nada a ver com a outra.

Comment: Então, isso que eu fiz foi comentar e não responder, logo estou falando de uma curiosidade minha, é off-topic a minha pergunta/comentário, eu queria entender o que te levou a este entendimento sobre a resposta não ser clara ou ser insuficiente ou incorreta (como você disse: *Ao meu ver a resposta está incorreta*). Fique a vontade para decidir debater ou não sobre isto comigo, é apenas uma curiosidade minha e não tem obrigação alguma de seguir conversando, mas gostaria muito de saber e assim eu e você poderiamos ajudar o autor da resposta a melhora-la, entendeu?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Foi a forma como ele escreveu. Ele colocou que i++ retorna o valor inicial de i e ++i retorna o valor incrementado. Na minha visão, isso apenas diz como o código foi executado, mas não diz porque que isso acontece. Uma resposta mais adequada seria: i++ atribui e depois incrementa e ++i incrementa e depois atribui. Além disso, se i =0; e o i++ é chamado várias vezes, dizer que i++ retorna o valor inicial pode induzir quem está aprendendo achar que o valor retornado será 0. Pelo menos foi isso que imaginei quando li a primeira vez.

Comment: @FagnerFonseca entenda uma coisa, ele é Português e não Brasileiro, logo pode ser que a maneira que ele escreveu talvez (não estou afirmando) não esteja levando ao entendimento necessário por alguma diferença regional, ou pode ser algo simplesmente que ele "comeu" uma virgula, ou "comeu" um "não", creio que possamos questionar ele sobre isto, afinal a resposta dele tem muitos votos e ela é encontrada por muitos iniciantes, o ideal é corrigir ela para que seja util para quem esta aprendendo, concorda?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Entendi, mas eu não quero invalidar a resposta não. Apesar da discussão ter girado em torno dessa resposta, meu questionamento maior era em relação a não poder opinar diferente da  auditoria. A essa altura do campeonato, após ler várias vezes a resposta, não vejo problemas em continuar do jeito que está, até porque existem outras respostas que em conjunto vão ajudar quem precisa a entender o quesito direito. Obrigado pelo debate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Aleatoriamente o sistema coloca algumas avaliações falsas para ver se você está analisando e prestando atenção ou só avaliando no automático.

Ele considera o que ocorreu antes para determinar qual deveria ser a sua ação correta. É claro que as ações anteriores podem ser erradas e você estar correto.

Então o sistema de auditoria considera que se teve um 7 a 1 a Alemanha é absurdamente melhor que o Brasil, mesmo que isto não seja verdade.

Acontece com todo mundo, até moderadores. Então não se preocupe com este fato. É chato, mas faz parte. Aqui ou ali é normal e não fez nada errado.

Há um problema sério que muita gente não analisa direito. Pra falar a verdade acho que vários usuários já deveria ter o privilégio de analisar cassado.

Há outro problema mais complicado que é as pessoas acharem que algo é certo e na verdade ser errado. Pelo que vejo raramente há problema quando as pessoas acham que algo está errado (quando um acha errado não conta, aí tem muito falso positivo).

Se continua com a mesma opinião faça o que achar que deve. Como você já se identificou, por que não comenta para a resposta ser melhorada?

Eu concordo que a forma como ela está escrita ela está parcialmente errada, mas eu sei que o usuário sabe o certo, só não se expressou bem, mas acho que ele vai melhorar.

De fato lá tem respostas melhores.

Aí mostra o que eu sempre digo, uma resposta aceita e/ou com votos positivos atraem votos positivos mesmo que ela esteja errada (isto deveria mudar). O mesmo vale para quem respondeu, mas isso vale mais para os primeiros votos, os outros aparecem pela tendência já mostrada.

@@Sergio @@acklay

Comment: O uso de @@Sergio e @@acklay é para notificar aqueles usuários? Se sim, isso funciona porque você é moderador ou pode ser usado por qualquer um?

Comment: @ramaral estou testando se funciona neste caso, sei que funciona em chat, mas só para moderadores, então, não se anime :)

Comment: É pena :( Tenho noção do porquê do mecanismos de notificações ser restrito no entanto seria útil, em algumas situações, que ele fosse mais alargado.

Comment: @ramaral é, daria para fazer de um jeito que evitasse abuso, mas já sabe minha posição sobre porque isto não acontece. Seria simples colocar um critério que a pessoa só pode usar por quem tem privilégio (baseado em rep), quantidade bem limitada por semana ou mês, não enviar para quem desative o recebimento disto, moderadores poderem tirar o privilégio se constatar uso indevido.

Comment: Qual seria o erro ou imprecisão na resposta do Sergio?